# C# if statement with array.length

Tags: c#, arrays, if-statement

I have an array and a if statement that, for some reason, is not doing what I want it to do. So a user have to enter 5 numbers in a textbox and then the program should store it in an array, all fine here.

But then this if statement right. It crashes when the user puts in the final number. And if I change `<=` to `<` the code runs fine but doesn't store the final input.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int i = 0;
    int averageOf5;
    int[] numbers = new int[4];

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ( i <= numbers.Length)
        {
            numbers[i] =  Convert.ToInt32(textBoxUserNumbers.Text);

            i = i + 1;

            textBoxUserNumbers.Text = String.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            int Added5 = 0;

            Added5 = numbers.Sum(); 

            averageOf5 = Added5 / numbers.Length;

            textBoxAverageResult.Text = Convert.ToString(averageOf5);                 
        }
    }

    //Just for test purpose
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (int numbersOutput in numbers)
        {
            //textBoxAverageResult.Text = numbersOutput; 

            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(numbersOutput));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the declaration of the numbers array:

```
int[] numbers = new int[4];
```

should be

```
int[] numbers = new int[5];
```

And the change you made from `<=` to `<` is correct. Your array is now of length 5, but the array being 0-indexed, your `i` variable should through `0,1,2,3,4`.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. I didn't actully realize that when you declared an array you actully had to put the number of how many things you want to get stored. I thought it was more like if I put 4 it would be 0,1,2,3,4 but now I understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should declare your array with the size of 5 not 4

```
int[] numbers = new int[5];
```

Then this will work as expected:

```
if(i < numbers.Length)
```